# two sitemaps - possible problems?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I am using a web shop software and for some reason the main page (`http://www.mysite.com/`) is not being listed / generated within the automatic sitemap.xml while every other page is.

**My question now:** Without dabbling to much into technicalities and why the page is not being generated in the first place I would like to know if this problem can be solved by just simply manually creating an additional sitemap file (calling it sitemap-home.xml) which just contains information related to the index and submit it?

e.g.:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
      <url>
        <loc>http://www.mysite.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2013-05-05</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
      </url>
    </urlset>
```

Would this approach work and if so, would there be any considerable downsides?

Some expert advise would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There will not be a problem. At least Google will merge and ignore issues between sitemaps such as duplicate entries.

That being said, it is probably less maintenance to fix the source problem. It really *should* not be that hard even if it takes special code in the sitemap generated to just add the homepage at the beginning of the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

You could just ignore  the whole thing: Google and Bing will crawl and index the main page regardless. The frequency will depend on how often the page is updated.

Your situation *might* be a problem for a busy news site which *must* publish first about some burning topics. But for a web shop, no problem at all.